# nmcli - command line means to delete all wifi / wlan0 connections

Tags: wifi, nmcli, interface

I'd like to delete all active or inactive Wifi connections on interface `wlan0`, with the intention of having a known-empty clean slate to set things up. Is this possible?

I was hoping for something like

```
nmcli connection delete device wlan0
```

or

```
nmcli dev show wlan0 delete
```

but no such luck.

Or is there a means to do this with `iw`?  I found a means to delete the interface, but not connections.

Comment: Try "ip link set wlan0 down". It will certainly kill all the connections, It's not clear what you mean by a "clean slate". If you have SSID broadcast turned on then connections may re-connect.

Answer (score 4):

`nmcli --terse connection show` will list connections as lines with colon-separated fields. So you could do something like this:

```
nmcli --terse connection show | cut -d : -f 1 | \
  while read name; do echo nmcli connection delete "$name"; done
```

This will display a series of `nmcli connection delete` commands, one per line. If the output looks correct, remove the word `echo` and it will execute the commands instead of displaying them.

`\` indicates that a long line has been split in two for readability; if you write it all in one line, you should omit the `\`.

Comment: You could use `nmcli --terse --fields=name` (or equivalently `nmcli -t -f name`) to avoid the need for `cut` here I think - also note that this will delete connections on ALL interfaces (not just "on interface wlan0")

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli connection delete <connection name>` works fine for me. It deletes connections (like the known wifi networks and such).
Using `iw` you can add and delete devices (like `wlan0`). Requires root privilage.
`sudo iw dev wlan0 del`
To create new one:
`sudo iw phy phy0 interface add wlan0  type managed`
Here phy0 is the physical device of your computer (NIC or such). To know the name of phy use `iw phy`. It'll return a list of physical devices and their capabilities.

Comment: I can do nmcli con del <name> for single connections  I'm trying to find if something like 'nmcli connection delete ALL dev wlan0'  exists.  Ie, take down -all- my wifi connections in one shot.